# What is the file structure of the Share Webscript extensions for Alfresco 4.0.3+

Tags: module, alfresco

I've been reading [David Drapers' blog](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/ddraper/2012/05/22/customizing-share-javascript-widget-instantiation-part-1/) on the new feature - the extension of share webscripts, but I didn't find any working examples. What is the file naming and structure convention?

From what I gather, I have a module configuration file, and I don't know how to name it or where to put it (`share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco`?)

Also, I understood that my custom client side resources (.js and .css files) go to `META-INF/custom-dashlet/extension/` in the JAR file. Is this correct? Finally, the *.get.js and *.get.html.ftl go to `webscripts/com/mycompany/mypackage/*`?

So I have now:

```
*share/WEB-INF/lib/mypackage.jar*
```

and in it:

```
*META-INF/mypackage/extension/myfile.js
webscripts/com/mycompany/mypackage/myfile.get.js
webscripts/com/mycompany/mypackage/myfile.get.html.ftl
*
```

and the

```
*share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/something.xml*
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an AMP (Alfresco Module Package) for your customisations, or something else? And if you're not trying to create an AMP, is there a reason why?

Comment: I don't really know. I made my previous customizations by just copying the code out to shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/* and then adding my stuff. Now they say you don't copy the whole code, you just extend the existing dashlet or whatever. So maybe I am looking for a structure for an AMP, I just didn't know it :)

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on the Alfresco Module Management Tool (MMT) and Alfresco Module Package (AMP), then tweak your question to be whatever is left that you don't understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was also posted to the Alfresco forums here: https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=46438

The answer provided was as follows:

An extension module a Surf configuration object so you should place XML files containing module configuration in any of the locations where Surf config gets picked up... e.g. `<web-server>/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-data` (there are lots of places where Surf configuration gets picked up, but `alfresco/site-data` on the `classpath` is the most common). Extension config files should be placed in the `extensions` folder within the directory. So you could place an extension config file in: `alfresco/site-data/extensions` or `alfresco/web-extension/site-data/extensions`, for example.

You could create a JAR file containing this folder structure. Everything that the extension refers to (e.g. WebScripts, other Surf config objects such as Pages, Template-Instances, Components, etc) should just be placed in their normal location. These can also be built into a JAR file.

If you want to access resources (e.g. CSS, images, JS) from a JAR file then place them in the META-INF folder of the JAR. You should place your JAR file in the `<web-server>/webapps/share/WEB-INF/lib` directory (obviously your server will need to be restarted to pick up new JAR contents).

WebScripts should be in (on the classpath):

```
alfresco/site-webscripts
alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts
webscripts
```

You can also configure other locations in the Surf configuration from which to load Surf config `objects/WebScripts`. It's pretty much endlessly customizable but you should probably just stick to the default locations configured for Share.